# How to Remove Role Cache on Sign Out in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, caching

I have a custom RoleProvider and I want to remove the role cache on logout. The roles I have are "Administrator" and "Member", which are working accordingly to authorize every page/action I have in my application but when I try to change the role of the user within the same opened browser it's not updating. Here's the scenario:

.. I sign in as user "User1" with "Administrator" role and browse administrator pages and logs him out.
.. I sign in as user "Admin" with Administrator role and change User1's role to "Member" role. I checked the database and his RoleID has been changed. I log the "Admin" out.
.. I sign in back "User1" and browse the application. I can still browse administrator pages even though this user has already a "Member" role. I log him out.
.. I close the browser and open the application in a new browser. I sign in as user "User1" and browse the application. I can only browse member pages now.

How can I remove the cache of the role on browser on sign out/logoff?

I already tried sending an expired cookie back to the browser but there's still nothing..

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Comment: Just resolved my problem.. I added Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest on Global.asax.cs and assigned a new GenericPrincipal to HttpContext.Current.User. :)